# Is there any posibillity to create conditioanl access policy only for Sharepoint online excluding its dependencies like ms teams?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, policy

I want to allow internal users to access SharePoint sites only from selected IP ranges. However, for external users and guest I want to allow to access it from any network.

So, I created a conditional access policy from Azure AD to implement it which was successful as expected. But there is another problem that I was not aware of, it is now blocking internal users to sign in to MS Teams from outside of the whitelisted IP ranges which I dont want. So is there any workaround to include only sharepoint not the MS teams.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create a conditional access policy in Azure AD, the policy will be applied to all Microsoft 365 apps like SharePoint, Teams and so on. You can set access control policy only on SharePoint level to solve this issue. Don't forget to remove or disable the policy you set in Azure AD before doing this.

1. Go to **SharePoint admin center**.
2. Select **Policies** from the left-side navigation.
3. Select **Access control**.
4. Select **Network location**.
5. Turn on Allow access only from specific IP address ranges and enter IP addresses or ranges in the below textbox.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allen_MSFT. I think It helped to figure out the solution.

Comment: Please remember to mark this answer if it is helpful to you :-)